# Mixing smart pointers to class objects with class objects

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, reference

I have a code where by design some classes use a factory function to generate the actual class, and others do not. Many classes have functions with the same names implemented and those functions are called sequentially (see below). This design results in mixing smart pointers to objects and objects itself. Is the code below bad design and should I use smart pointers everywhere?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{
    public:
        void print_name() { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

class B
{
    public:
        virtual void print_name() = 0;
        static std::unique_ptr<B> factory(const int n);
};

class B1 : public B
{
    public:
        void print_name() { std::cout << "B1\n"; }
};

class B2 : public B
{
    public:
        void print_name() { std::cout << "B2\n"; }
};

std::unique_ptr<B> B::factory(const int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return std::make_unique<B1>();
    else if (n == 2)
        return std::make_unique<B2>();
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Illegal option");
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::unique_ptr<B> b1 = B::factory(1);
    std::unique_ptr<B> b2 = B::factory(2);

    // The block below disturbs me because of mixed . and ->
    a.print_name();
    b1->print_name();
    b2->print_name();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I have added smart pointers to the example following the comments below.

Comment: Consistent code is much easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: So you suggest to also make `a` a pointer?

Comment: as Valentin mentioned below raw pointers are really undesirable in modern C++ code. I'd use std::unique_ptr in this case. You should research smart pointers to make sure you understand which one is better for you.

Comment: @Sergei, read my comment to Valentin's post. This is not a discussion about smart pointers vs normal pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a reasonable design to me. In the client code you will work through the base class interface.

```
class Base {};
class A: public Base {};
class B: public Base {};
class B1: public B {};
class B2: public B {};

class Factory {
  std::unique_ptr<Base> create(const int n) {
    // Instantiate a concrete class based on n
    return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new A());
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the variable names while you were writing the answer. Now there is a little confusion between your `Base` and mine.

Comment: Why would you derive all classes form the same `Base`  even if they have nothing in common?

Comment: @Chiel they seem to have identical interface in your code. This creates a reasonable assumption they are related.

Comment: Proper naming helps avoid confusions.

Comment: I agree. I renamed the variables back to be consistent with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should avoid using pointers, if not needed. Topics like Return Value Optimization make them optional in most cases. Also, don't use C-Style-Pointers. C++11 introduced the memory-header, which includes many useful smart pointers.

And yeah, I feel like using those pointers in such a program is a bad design decision.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post a solution in the form of code. I know that smart pointers are an option here, but that does not change the question at all, because then I'd be mixing smart pointers to objects and objects.

Comment: Sorry: wrong branch. @Chiel it doesn't change anything. If A, B and C are related and can be manipulated through the same interface - the best option is to have one base class (probably abstract). This will greatly simplify the client code.

Comment: Somebody already postet a nice solution for this. Sorry for not giving code samples, but smart pointers are a pretty popular topic in C++ and there are alot of articles and code samples about it, which can be aquired by a quick search. And @Sergei was right. This might not be a discussion about whether smart or raw pointers should be used, it is one about improving your code design. In this case the smart pointers are the solution. Either that, or you take my advice, use copies and don't worry about it. A modern compiler would already take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the mix, why does the code disturb you? What do you think could actually go badly because of it? Do you think the difference really hurts readability?

Yes the lines that call print look different, and that difference tells you that the objects are being managed in a different way.

There's no obvious benefit to them being made the same, if a developer can't understand both . and -> then you have much bigger problems.

I've worked on a codebase where nearly everything was handled by shared pointers for consistency, even though some things shouldn't be pointers and most aren't really shared. Needless inconsistency should be avoided but it really isn't helpful to be consistent in cases where that hides legitimate difference.

One benefit of your code over all pointers is that since a is not a pointer you can sure that a is not null.

Comment: you are just throwing polymorphism out of the window. You'd better learn how to use it to your advantage. This design won't scale beyond the given example.

Comment: You've no idea what I know about polymorphism. Even with polymorphic classes the combination of value and pointer use is fine if in this case 'a' should definitely be an A and be a local variable. A mistake I've seen some people make when they misunderstand polymorphism is to assume that if 2 classes have any method name in common they should share a base. From the class names A,B,C Base its impossible to tell whether A should be modelled as is-a Base only then should it inherit from  Base, and even then object a can be a local non pointer variable if required.

Comment: How about every single public method like in this case?
factory() doesn't really belong to the object.

Comment: You are also forgetting about static polymorphism which doesn't require a common base class.

Comment: No I have not forgotten about static polymorphism thank you.

Comment: "How about every single public method like in this case?" No not even then. Its all about whether the " is-a " rule can be met. Impossible to tell that with such simple example code. Anyway I've suggested the use of polymorphism and therefore pointer and -> is suitable, but that its use is not incompatible with having a local by-value object. Even if class A is edited to derive from base, there is not a problem with holding object a by-value.